# 404 not found error on Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm very new to AWS and Nginx.

When I get an access to my elastic ip address for web server EC2 instance, I get a 404 not found error.

How come it shows 404 not found error although I have uploaded files to the directory I set as root directory in nginx.conf file?

After I edited the nginx.conf file, I did reload nginx as well.

## On EC2

```
$ ls sites/
LICENSE  README.md  css  fonts  index.html  js
```

## nginx.conf

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name MY_IP_ADDRESS_HERE;
        root /sites/;
    }
}
```

## Additional Information

I get a default nginx page when I set the root directory to "/usr/share/nginx/html/" in nginx.conf file, so the server is working ok.

Comment: It looks like your root directory configuration doesn't match your actual directory. Are you sure you put your files under the absolute path '/sites'? Have you further checked the permission on this folder (it must be readable by the nginx user)?

Comment: I uploaded files under home/ec2-user/sites! is it the reason why I'm getting 404!!??

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't upload files to absolute path '/sites'. now it works!!