# How to work around the 404 error on nginx?

Tags: angular, nginx, single-page-application

I have an angular 4 SPA app and I'am using docker for production. Looks fine so far. Via terminal I go to `/dist` folder and from there I let docker point to the content of `dist` with the following command:
`docker run -d -p 9090:80 -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html nginx:alpine`

I call: `localhost:9090` on the browser and can access the app.
The issue is when I reload the page once again and/or as specific route, then I get `404 Not Found` and the nginx version e.g. `nginx/1.13.5`.

I have been searching and found this issue: [404 not found error on Nginx Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735679/404-not-found-error-on-nginx), but unfortunately no solution.

How to work around this and avoid the 404 error? Is it a config steps which I do have to edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that in the default nginx config it only uses the `index` directive. What you need is the [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive which will first try the `uri` then it will go to the `index.html`

To do this you need to pass in your own default virtual host config. Something like the following should work. This is based on [Nginx's Docker Github](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/alpine/nginx.vh.default.conf)

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index  index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

After that is it should be just making that file as a volume in the right spot.

`docker run -d -p 9090:80 -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html -v (path_to_your_config):/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf nginx:alpine`

Comment: Great, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I just can't find the default virtual host config. I 'am a mac user and normally the default `nginx.conf` on mac is: `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, but I just can't find it there. Any hint?

Comment: You create the file like what I have suggested in your project root. Then pass that in. Don't mess with nginx.conf in the container. I ran docker from the root of my project to test this by doing `docker run -d -p 9090:80 -v $(pwd)/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html -v $(pwd)/test.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf nginx:alpine`