# I am trying to build angular 4 application which is new to me. After I pushed into nginx server getting some Issue

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx

1. The problem is when directly redirecting to
   http://localhost:4200/about working fine but after pushing into
   nginx server, when I try to redirect to www.webpage.com/about
   getting error(nginx 404 error).
                   But its working fine when you redirect to www.webpage.com and then click on about. 
                   Getting error only I am trying to open direct url as www.webpage.com/about or www.webpage.com/contact or
   www.webpage.com/blog

   ```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
   import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
   import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
   import { appRoutes } from "./app-routing.module";

   import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
   import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
   import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
   import { ClientsComponent } from './clients/clients.component';
   import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
   import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';



   @NgModule({
       declarations: [
           AppComponent,
           HomeComponent,
           AboutComponent,
           BlogComponent,
           ClientsComponent,
           ContactComponent,
           PageNotFoundComponent
       ],
       imports: [
           BrowserModule,
           AppRoutingModule,
           HttpModule,
           FormsModule,
           ReactiveFormsModule,

           RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
       ],
       providers: [
       ],
       bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule {
   }


    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
       import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

       import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
       import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

       import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
       import { ClientsComponent } from './clients/clients.component';

       import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
       import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';




       export const appRoutes: Routes = [
           { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
           { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
           { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
           { path: 'clients', component: ClientsComponent },
           { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
           { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
           { path: 'page-not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
           { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
       ];

       @NgModule({
           imports: [
               RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
           ],
           exports: [
               RouterModule
           ]
       })
       export class AppRoutingModule {
       }
   ```

Comment: Please paste your code directly into the text of your question as opposed to linking an image.

Comment: Does the console output any error ?

Comment: Thanks for response! I didn't get any console errors. nginx server directly throwing 404 error.@Boulboulouboule. But its working fine in my local machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to work around the 404 error on nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077428/how-to-work-around-the-404-error-on-nginx)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure your web server to redirect all unknown (404) requests to index.html, which will allow the Angular application to then route your user to the desired route/view.

Comment: Thanks for the response! can you please provide me sample code or any other links to help me  for that @Krish

Comment: I know how to set up tomcat server but at this point i was not sure how to set up for ngINx.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
```

Source : [How do I force redirect all 404's (or every page, whether invalid or not) to the homepage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487365/how-do-i-force-redirect-all-404s-or-every-page-whether-invalid-or-not-to-the)

Answer (score 0):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

This line has to be added in the `nginx.conf` incase of Windows server or in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` in case of ubuntu server.

That piece of code will look for angular paths before throwing a 404 error.

[angular deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) check this out