# Config nginx to serve angular app in different languages

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, internationalization

I'am using docker to serve my angular application which is using i18n serve different languages.

I point docker to the **`dist`** folder with the following command:
**`docker run -d -p 9090:80 -v "$(pwd)/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html" -v "$(pwd)/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" nginx:alpine`**

I also have the [try_files](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/alpine/nginx.vh.default.conf) directive saved in the app root as **`app.conf`** in order to avoid the [404 NGINX error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077428/how-to-work-around-the-404-error-on-nginx) when reloading the page/app or targeting a specific route/context directly.

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index  index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

Everything works as expected and I can reach :**`localhost:9090/home`** except when I try to navigate to a specific language e.g. **`localhost:9090/es/`** or **`localhost:9090/en/`**
Then I get the error:

**`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'en' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'en'`**

The folders: **`/es`** and **`/en`** are generated under **`dist`** folder with the following script saved in **`package.json`**:

**`"build-i18n": "for lang in en de; do ng build --output-path=dist/$lang --aot -prod --i18n-file=src/i18n/messages.$lang.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=$lang; done"`**

and they contain all the needed bunlde-files to run and serve the app.

The expected behavior should be when I call the app with a specific language e.g. **`localhost:9090/en/`**, ittt should be served in englisch e.g.: **`localhost:9090/en_US/home`** and if I call **`localhost:9090/es/`**, the app should be served in spanisch e.g. **`localhost:9090/es_ES/home`** cause I'am using the **`LOCALE_ID`** module from **`@angular/core`**

This was the case before I added the **try_files directive** under the root app.. it was working fine reaching all the different languages.

So, what do have I to change and/or in **`add.conf`** file to avoid the error mentioned before?

Comment: Give `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` a try.

Comment: I can see a kind of progress but not really a fix... Chrome throws: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
localhost/:1 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:9090/styles.3774f59546156175f4b7.bundle.css".` I think it should have to do with the additional backslash in `$uri/`

Comment: The backslash has to do with the second argument checking a directory, the first checks the exact path, and the last defaults to `index.html`. `Unexpected token <` makes me think you may have a forgotten merge conflict in that file.

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly mean with "...merge conflict in that file".
Anyway, now Chrome and FireFox are throwing following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.ad37cd45a71cb38eee76.bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at polyfills.ad37cd45a71cb38eee76.bundle.js:1`. It's a strange behavior!

Comment: @TJBiddle: Ok, I found out that the angular-cli in a way is generating `HTML` instead of javascript for the following 2 files:  `inline.ef2cca55df62b04c3a6e.bundle.js` and : `main.f6759214c702206e325d.bundle.js`. That's why the error: `Unexpected token <` as HTML beginns with: `<!docytpe html>`.